# In PHP, how can I escape single quotes in my string before inserting into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, replace

I have a lot of text to insert into a MySQL table using PHP. Part of the text looks like this example:

```
Yes, this is 'great'!
```

To fill this into an SQL Statement, I need to escape the `'`.

I'm using an ereg-replace `$text=mb_ereg_replace("'","\\'", $text);` to make the following work:

```
$sql="insert into mytable (msg) values ('".$text."')";
```

Now I found out that there is also another text-style, where I have to save to MySQL something like this:

```
As you can see the \' world\' is a "disc"!
```

So I tried adding more mb_ereg_replace like this:

```
$text=mb_ereg_replace("'","\\'", $text);
$text=mb_ereg_replace("\\","\\\\", $text);
```

But this does not work, I just get the error message: `PHP Warning:  mb_ereg_replace(): mbregex compile err: end pattern at escape in [...]`

What causes this? I probably made some mistake, but can't find it!

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: I'm using `mb_ereg_replace`. It looks like, this is not deprecated: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php The Problem is, that there does not exist an multibyte-version of `preg_replace`, like `mb_preg_replace()`. So it looks like `mb_ereg_replace` is the onlyest way the use multibyte (UTF-8) string with search/replace on regular expressions!?

Comment: Yes, you can use `preg_replace` -- you can use the `u` switch to enable UTF-8 in the `preg_xx` functions. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/php.html for more info.

Comment: oh, thank you! that would be helpful, if there would be any hint at the preg_replace documentation-page from php.net Thank you! :-)

Comment: you're right; this is the one area I can think of where the PHP docs aren't that great. They're normally pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to escape your strings.

```
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($text);
```

Or better, use PDO and parameterized queries.

Comment: oh yeah, that's it! It's so easy, but this function is absolutely new for me! Thank you!!

Comment: since you are relatively new at PHP, it is highly recommended that you learn about some of the newer methods.  Try and avoid using `mysql_` functions as they have been deprecated (meaning they are going away, and will soon not work at all, for some very good reasons).  You can do the same thing with `mysqli_`.  These also accept prepared statements and are a nice and easy transition. :) See an example below, which will both solve your problem and quite a few others.

Answer (score 1):

There's a much better way, and you won't need to worry about escaping your strings ever again.    Using prepared statements in `mysqli` or `PDO` will both make large queries (ones with many rows) run much faster, they are secure, you don't have to worry about (most types of) SQL injection and they are easy to learn.   the strings will just be accepted as is into your database without the risk of breaking your code.

Here's an example with `mysqli`:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (columnname) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $text);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Basicallly, by binding the parameters before it goes in, it just accepts any string the way you create it, and there's no need to escape anything.'

Here's the same thing using PDO.  This does essentially the same thing but has the advantage of both working with multiple different database types (such as for instance Oracle or PostgreSQL) and also lends itself to some nifty modification due to the classes associated.

```
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (columname)
        VALUES (:text)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':text', $text);
        $stmt->execute();
    catch(PDOException $e)
        {
        echo "Oops, didn't work: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    $conn = null;
```